# Boundedness and Convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n(t)=t^n-t^{n+1} $ and $y_n(t)=n(t^n-t^{n+1})$ be two function sequences defined on $[0,1].$ I need to prove if these two function sequences are bounded and convergent in $L^1 [0,1].$

Since the subject is new to me, i will appreciate any hint. Thanks

Comment: You should know how to get a maximum and minimum value of a function by standard methods (check first derivative, etc…). Show that this maximum is bounded for both functions. Because it obviously holds that $0 \le x_n \le y_n$ it's enough to check this for $y_n$ and you will get that both functions are bounded. On the other hand you have$y_n \to y$ pointwise $x_n = \frac{y_n}{n}$ and if $y_n$ converges pointwise it follows that $x_n \to 0$. Show that this also holds in L^1 by using dominated convergence theorem because both functions are bounded.

Comment: Since you are working on $[0,1]$, you can say that $|x_n|=x_n$ and $|y_n|=y_n$. After that, apply the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the $L^1(0,1)$-norm is
\begin{align*}
\|v\|_{L^1(0,1)} = \int_0^1 |v(t)|dt.
\end{align*}
In your case you just have to integrate $x_n$ and $y_n$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\|x_n\|_{L^1(0,1)} = \int_0^1 t^n - t^{n+1}dt \quad \text{and}\quad\|y_n\|_{L^1(0,1)} = n\int_0^1 t^n - t^{n+1}dt.
\end{align*}
But these integrals are very easy to solve. What can you say about convergence and boundedness?